# Wordpress Facebook Like button count problems

Tags: wordpress, facebook, button, count, facebook-like

I have a problem with my Like button, counter actually, that wasn't there before.

My blog is at: blog.matickos.com
My FB page is: facebook.com/MaticKosPhotography

I use my blog, have a FB page and a FB profile. I write a post on my blog, then post the link on my FB page and share that on my FB profile. In the past, all these shares would be counted as Likes and would show up next to the Like button on the blog. Same with the actual Likes. If 3 people would like the link on my FB page and 4 people on my FB profile, I’d get 7 more likes. But now it seems that doesn’t work anymore. Now it seems, it's only counting the actual Like clicks on the blog post itself, nothing else.
I usually get very low Like clicks on the blog, much more on my FB page and profile, so this is a bummer for me :/

I use these WP plugins:
WP Facebook Like by Johnny Chadda
WP Facebook Open Graph protocol by Chuck Reynolds
and
Facebook Like Thumbnail by Ashfame

I've tried everything. Disabling everything, different plugins, nothing works.
I also use Google 'Plus one' Button plugin by Miko Andras; I've read some people had problems with google+ working with FB Like. I've disabled it, no luck.

I've also created a FB App, so I have a AppID as well, but that didn't make any change. :/
I can't see any problems in the Linter either.

Why aren't my shares/likes counted together as they should be?? :/
Any ideas?
Pls help!

TIA,
Mat

Answer (score 1):

i already used this functionality in wordpress, [facebook like counter](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) will help you.

OR

put this code in your `<head>` section

1)  `<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>`

Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.

2) `<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/MaticKosPhotography " data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>`

your problem will be solved :)

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure we understand each other.. I'm not looking for a Like button for my FB page, I need the Like button on all my blog posts to work/count correctly.
For instance, my previous post (http://blog.matickos.com/2012/01/sedmica/) shows it has only 2 likes. But the post was shared on my FB Page + FB profile and got 3 likes on FB Page and 6 likes + 3 comments on my FB profile. So the count should be around 16, not 2. The Like button on the blog appears to only count likes on the blog, nothing else. No shares/likes on my FB Page & Profile.. 
This used to work, now it doesn't.. :/